# Array of objects in javascript not returning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sqlite

I have a function which returns a list of objects in Javascript, and I'm calling this function from another and attempting to use some of the values from it, but whenever I try to access said values, they come back undefined.

This is my function which generates the list - the idea is that it creates a sqlite3 database if it does not exist, and returns an array containing every event.

```
function listAllEvents() {
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    const db = new sqlite3.Database('schedule.db');

    const selectionArray = [];

    db.serialize(() => {
        db.run(`
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (
            name text,
            date text,
            id text primary key
            )
        `);

        db.all('SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY date', [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            rows.forEach((row) => {
                selectionArray.push(row);
            });
        });
    });
    return selectionArray;
}
```

I call this function from another, but when I try to access values from the array, they don't seem to be working and I can't quite figure it out.

```
function displayUpcomingEvents() {
    const events = listAllEvents();

    // console.log(events); <-- This line here! In the console, it correctly states the length of the array
    // console.log(events.length) <-- This line, however, returns 0. Why?
    // console.log(events[0]) <-- This doesn't work either, it just returns "undefined".

    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i += 1) {
        $('#upcomingEvents').after('<li>asdf</li>');
    }
}
```

For example, if I were to create two events in the database, through the console,

```
events is an Array(2) with indices
- 0: {name: "my_event", date: "2019-06-04", id: "c017c392d446d4b2"}
- 1: {name: "my_event_2", date: "2019-06-04", id: "6d655ac8dd02e3fd"},

events.length returns 0,
and events[0] returns undefined.
```

Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I'd suggest you to change that `events` name for your array. You almost hit `event`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason why this is happening, is because of the async nature of JS, that means all the `console.log` statements are getting executed before the successful execution of the `listAllEvents()` function,

So my suggestion is to try using the promises, and perform all the actions mentioned after the `listAllEvents()` function only when that function returns a promise.

You can also try making the function async and using await to wait for its successful execution. **(Much Smarter Choice will be using async)**

[Link to ASYNC Functions and Usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
[Link to Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Also you can check the validity of answer by doing `console.log(row)` where you are pushing rows to the array. You will observer that the `console.log(row)` will be executed at the last, after printing events and other log statements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function is returning the variable before a value is set. The `db.serialize` function will run asynchronously (outside the normal flow of the program) and the return statement will run immediately after. One thing you can do is use async/await in conjunction with `Promise`. In this case the the variable `results` will wait for the promise to be resolved before continuing to the next line.

```
async function listAllEvents() {    
    const selectionArray = [];

    let promise = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        db.serialize(() => {
            db.run(
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (
            name text,
                date text,
                id text primary key
                )
            );

            db.all('SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY date', [], (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    // add code here to reject promise
                    throw err;
                }

                rows.forEach((row) => {
                    selectionArray.push(row);
                });
                resolve(selectionArray);// resolve the promise
            });
        });
    });

    let results = await promise;
    return results; 
};

async function displayUpcomingEvents() {
    const events = await listAllEvents();

    // console.log(events); <-- This line here! In the console, it correctly states the length of the array
    // console.log(events.length) <-- This line, however, returns 0. Why?
    // console.log(events[0]) <-- This doesn't work either, it just returns "undefined".

    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i += 1) {
        $('#upcomingEvents').after('<li>asdf</li>');
    }
}
```

Note here that the `displayUpcomingEvents` function will also need to be async or  you cannot use the await keyword.

Additional reading for Promise keyword [MDN: Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Additional reading for Async/Await [MDN: Asyn/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)